# Github ssh key push only

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo and I was wondering if it is possible to remove the ability to push to a repo without a ssh key.

I have had a look and can't see anything about having only an ssh-key that will let me push rather than both ssh push and a push where I enter my username and password.

Thanks

Comment: is it a public or private repo?  by default everybody can always clone public repo's...

Comment: @rogerdpack what does cloning a repo in github have to do with pushing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. You can set up the remote to use SSH for both pulling/pushing.
2. You can use the configuration option `url.<base>.pushInsteadOf`. So, for example, if the repo remote's URL is `https://github.com/me/blah.git`, run `git config url.'git@github.com:'.pushInsteadOf 'https://github.com/'`. Now, when you try to push into `https://github.com/me/blah.git`, Git will use the SSH url instead of the HTTPS one.

---

You can't prevent pushing over HTTPS for all users in a GitHub repo, but if you host the repo on your own server you can elect not to serve it over HTTPS at all.

Comment: I want to be only be able to exclusively push with ssh

Comment: @bubblebath: `pushInsteadOf` *will* push over SSH, even when the HTTPS URL is specified.

Comment: Yes but that means another person can push over https, which is what I want to prevent

Comment: @bubblebath: You can't prevent that on GitHub. You can prevent it on a server you control, by not serving the repo over HTTPS.

Comment: Darn! If you write that as an answer I will accept it